# Should one bootstrap their data before a Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest, bootstrap

Should one bootstrap their data prior to conducting Random Forest (or in general for that matter) or not?
What are the pros and cons of doing so or not doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by "bootstrap"?

Comment: The RF algorithm does bootstrap on its own, which might be what you’re thinking of.

Comment: Bootstrapping @MichaelSidorov. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random Forest uses bagging technique which intrinsically uses bootstrapping.
Random forest uses about 2/3rd of bootstrapped data to build each tree and produces final output by averaging the results across all the trees. There are tons of resources available online on how random forest works.

Comment: And why would one do that? Pros and cons?

Comment: Bootstrapping in random forest is done to encourage diversity in different trees. This diversification is done to avoid overfitting or to reduce variance of the output although it comes with some added bias in each tree due to less data used to build it.